# Swiftmail doesn't send mail but no error, symfony on docker container

Tags: symfony, docker, symfony4, swiftmailer, mjml

I'm working on a symfony project on docker container and i set up a Mailer service which use swiftmailer and `notfloran/mjml-bundle` to send mail.
the mjml bndle needs mjml binary which i installed on the container with `npm install mjml`. 
In the code :

```
$mail = new \Swift_Message();
$mail
     ->setFrom($from)
     ->setTo($to)
     ->setSubject($subject)
     ->setBody($body)
     ->setContentType('text/mjml');
$this->mailer->send($mail);
```

The thing is that when i request the function which send the mail via the docker container, there is no error but it does not send the mail.
But when i start a server with `php -S adress -t public` and i request the function which send the mail, the mail is sent.

EDIT: i tried to log the processus. In the log there is a `mjml binary not found` but when i enter in the container the mjml command works

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this? Is there anything written to the error log?

Comment: Check junk/spam folder

Comment: @NicoHaase i just tried the log, i found an `mjml binary not found` error but the mjml binary are installed in the container

Comment: mjml might be in the container, but maybe it's not in the `PATH`, and thus can't be found... I believe `php -S ...` hands the path forward (from terminal). in docker and the contained system, the process handling php might not contain the path where mjml is located. find out which paths you got in the docker php process, and check with `which mjml` in docker, where the binary is located. maybe a symlink is enough...

Comment: @Jakumi there is a symfony config file in which i put the binary path like ```'%kernel.project_dir%/node_modules/.bin/mjml'```

Comment: okay, so the error message is quite clear, the binary cannot be found. so something must be off. the first thing after changing configs is to clear the cache (`bin/console cache:clear; bin/console cache:warmup`). then I would test with `bin/console swiftmailer:email:send` maybe with some `-vvv` to see what's happening. and take it from there. append the results of your finding to your question, if the problem isn't solved then...

Comment: @Jakumi in the container terminal bin/console `swiftmailer:email:send` do send mails, so the problem is the `mjml`. I cleared the cache many times

Comment: okay, `swiftmailer:email:send` does take a `--mailer=...` argument, where you might probably set the mjml mailer?

Comment: No , swiftmailer is already configured to support mjml with as  ```->setContentType('text/mjml');```

Answer (score 0):

SwiftMailer is kinda hard to debug in that situation. I had a similiar one.

If you're using docker then you have to make sure that an email client is setup and configured so that php can use it.

I'm using php:7.4-fpm and adding msmtp through my own dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y msmtp 

# msmtp - mailer
COPY build/etc/msmtprc /etc/msmtprc
RUN chmod 600 /etc/msmtprc
```

msmtprc file:

```
account default
host mailhost.mobilcom.de
port 25
auth off
user null
password null
from "docker@klarmobil.de"
logfile /var/log/msmtp.log
```

And add to php.ini:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/msmtp -t
```

Then try again to send you mail